# Binary Tree Extraction code

Tags: c, binary-tree

I have pre-written code that I'm trying to wrap my head around:

```
int maxExtract(node **tree)
{
    node *prev = NULL;
    node *curr = *tree;
    int ret;

    if(curr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Tree is empty!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    while( curr->right != NULL )
    {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->right;
    }

    ret = curr->data;
    if( prev != NULL )
        prev->right = curr->left;
    else if( curr == *tree )
        *tree = curr->left;
    free(curr);
    return ret;
}
```

I understand everything except the `else if (curr == *tree)` condition. I think it's saying that if the max node ends up being the root. However, wouldn't you need to change more connections than that after the else if, like to connect the right and left side of the tree to this new root after extracting the old one?

Comment: Your code doesn't work for extracting an arbitrary node; it can only extract the maximum, i.e. the right-most node. The root can only be the maximum node, if it has no subtree to its right.

Answer (score 3):

> I think it's saying that if the max node ends up being the root.

That is *exactly* what it means and, if that's the case, then there can be *nothing* in the right side of that node because, if there were, the maximum would be somewhere in that (right) sub-tree, not at the root.

So let's consider the tree where the root *is* the maximum (and `A1/A2` are arbitrary sub-trees, including empty ones):

```
     MAX
    /
   x
  / \
A1   A2
```

To extract the maximum value, what you want to be left with is simply:

```
   x
  / \
A1   A2
```

So the operation you want to perform is to make `x` the new root of the tree - this is done with the line in your code:

```
*tree = curr->left;
```

---

I'd probably write it slightly differently to explicitly handle the disparate cases rather than relying on things happening or not happening depending on various decisions in the middle of the code. By that, I mean:

```
int maxExtract (node **tree) {
    // Handle empty tree as error.

    if (*tree == NULL) {
        printf ("Tree is empty!\n");
        exit (-1);
    }

    // Handle root is max, i.e., has no right subtree.

    if ((*tree)->right == NULL) {
        node *nodeToDelete = *tree;       // Save root for deletion.
        int retVal = nodeToDelete->data;  // Get data to return.
        *tree = nodeToDelete->left;       // Set new root.
        free (nodeToDelete);              // Delete old root.
        return retVal;                    // Return old root value.
    }

    // Locate max and its previous.

    node *prev = *tree;
    node *curr = (*tree)->right;
    while (curr->right != NULL) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->right;
    }

    // Max has no right sub-tree but it MAY have a left one
    // which needs to be transferred as-is to the right of prev.

    int retVal = curr->data;    // Get data to return.
    node *nodeToDelete = curr;  // Save root for deletion.
    prev->right = curr->left;   // Transfer left sub-tree (or null).
    free (nodeToDelete);        // Delete old max.
    return retVal;              // Return old max value.
```

Comment: Awesome! I learn a lot from code so seeing your version against my teachers' helps me see the connection better. And I see, prev-> = curr->left is going to the possible node smaller than max that was on its left and is now taking the space of max. Our summer semester is taught by a math teacher so I'm not sure we're getting the best examples. Thanks!